# How to solve "Extra content at the end of the document" Error php

Tags: php, sql, database, localhost, port

I got a problem with the ports i think. I read about that problem before and people wrote there might be a problem with the server not allowing outgoing connections on the specified port. The problem is that I didn't declare any certain ports in the relevant php file.

Here the code:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
mysql_connect( 'localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock', 'root', '' );
mysql_select_db( 'chat' );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO chatitems VALUES ( null, null, '".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['user'] ).
            "', '".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['message'] ).
            "')" );
?> 
<success />
```

and here the error I get:

[image: This page contains the following errors:]

hope someone knows what to do

PS: My Webspace is bplaced.net and I manage my SQL Database via PhpMyAdmin

If you want to try it visit [fl-webdesign.org/chat/test.html](http://fl-webdesign.org/chat/test.html)

Comment: Can you remove the spaces everywhere when not needed and try again?

Comment: I already did but let me try again

Comment: I'm sorry there are no spaces left that I didn't delete. I also looked at the file in hex mode an looked in line 2 and at the end of the document for zero with spaces

Comment: Can you check the html generated source code in your browser? see if there is anything suspicious ?

Comment: I'm sorry there will only be the first line in the code box when editing my post but I posted the link to the page:
fl-webdesign.org/chat/test.html

Comment: Are you attaching any CSS code to your code which is not in the `style` tag?

Comment: I had a look at your generated html page, and it seems that you are having many problems connecting to the DB. Can you check that you are retrieving the data correctly?

Comment: I saw those problems too so it might be a problem with the server not allowing outgoing connections. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is, there might be **UTF-8 BOM** in your source code at this place:

```
<?php
-----^ // The BOM might be here.
header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
mysql_connect( 'localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock', 'root', '' );
mysql_select_db( 'chat' );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO chatitems VALUES ( null, null, '".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['user'] ).
            "', '".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['message'] ).
            "')" );
?> 
<success />
```

You can check it using a HEX Editor. Some resources for this would be:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)
- [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=utf+8+bom&aq=f&oq=utf+8+bom&aqs=chrome.0.57.3888j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=utf+8+bom+remover&oq=utf+8+bom+&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l3j0i22i30.6587.7874.0.9041.2.2.0.0.0.0.142.262.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.4jd7P001JLE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.aGc&fp=b64e532e7bac3b33&biw=1920&bih=979)

Comment: it's always 0A202020 which is space (20) and break i guess (0A)

Comment: `0A` is Break. `20` is space. Okay, remove the space then.

Comment: didn't help. I deleted all `20` via find and replace and got the same error